# tables package for Python 3.9.1?

Tags: python, installation, windows-10, pytables

This is my first question on here. Thank you very much in advance for your support.

I'm using Python 3.9.1 on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine and I've been trying to install the `tables` package by `pip install tables` but I always got the following error:

```
pip install tables
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.6.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9bkjlwp\\tables_8a3121807beb4fde8d73782dff1f349e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9bkjlwp\\tables_8a3121807beb4fde8d73782dff1f349e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-9_t31x9b'
         cwd: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u9bkjlwp\tables_8a3121807beb4fde8d73782dff1f349e\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u9bkjlwp\tables_8a3121807beb4fde8d73782dff1f349e\setup.py", line 634, in <module>
        libdir = compiler.has_function(package.target_function,
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 792, in has_function
        objects = self.compile([fname], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 313, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 267, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    * Using Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
    * USE_PKGCONFIG: False
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/32/847ee3f521aae6a0be380d923a736162d698586f444df1ac24b98c65025c/tables-3.6.1.tar.gz#sha256=49a972b8a7c27a8a173aeb05f67acb45fe608b64cd8e9fa667c0962a60b71b49 (from https://pypi.org/simple/tables/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I don't understand the error message but I suspect that it has to do with my Python version.

I did install all the prerequisite packages suggested on the [tables' homepage](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html) but I still got the error while installing the tables package.

I also tried to install with [.whl file](https://pypi.org/project/tables/#files), too but there was no file with cp39 in its name (which led me to the conclusion that there's no compatible version for Python 3.9 yet, but I might be wrong.)

Is there a way to install tables with Python 3.9.1? Thank you very much.

Comment: It says You need to have "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater" and it also gave u the link on where to find that. Please install it and check and try again.

Comment: You can get a pre-built version of PyTables for Python 3.9 from Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) website.

Comment: @SURYATEJA . Thank you for your suggestion. I tried installing the Microsoft Visual C++ following the link suggested in the error message. I still got another error message. This time it doesn't say about missing Microsoft Visual C++, though.

Comment: @martineau I tried following your suggestion and it worked. I can now import tables in my codes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've downloaded and installed the tables-3.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl from this [unofficial Windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) archive

Installed it with `pip install tables-3.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

**update**

The package was removed from the above link. I've found another source:
[pypi.bartbroe.re/tables/](https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/w6tyco5e/tables-3.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl)